# C++ Return a Type of object in a method of the same class

Tags: c++, class, types

To clarify I was wondering how to return the type of a class within the class definition.

Even though an answer was given I ended up reverting back to using a virtual function, which kind of made more sense in the long run.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `A A::someFunction();` ? Not sure what you are asking

Comment: "how would one return the value or type of a class in a method within its own method" is really very unclear.  It would be helpful to create a complete (pseudo-code) example of what you're aiming for.

Comment: Types are not objects in C++ and you can't return them. What is your exact use case? Looks like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Side note: a static class method that returns an object of the same type is a common way of implementing factory functions.

Comment: So I take there is no point of returning Creature, I have a lot to learn about c++ but that is why I am here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write `A` as the return type? Classes define user-defined types, meaning they can be used as return types. Sorry, if I misinterpreted your question though, and if there is an error, please point it out. Anyways, here is the code below:

```
class A
{
    //....
public:
   A someFunction();
   //.....
}

//implementation:
A A::someFunction()
{
    //Code....
}
```